# desktop browsers connect to ip address fine, but some mobile browsers don't

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, digital-ocean

I have a very simple one page rails app that I am hosting on Digital Ocean.  I finally got it up and running and I am able to see the site if I go to the ip address in my browser.  However, I tried to go to the ip address on my phone and I am getting connection refused.  I am using Chrome android.  The weird thing is that I tried my phone's stock internet app (I have an HTC One m8) and it allows the connection.  I also downloaded firefox for android and it would not connect to the site.

Any idea why desktop browsers and my phone's stock browser connects to the site but chrome and firefox for mobile won't?

Comment: Some ideas. In the browsers where the app times out have you looked at the browser debugger information? And although it sounds cliche, have you cleared the browser cache in all your browsers and devices?